# Doubt: Irreducibles are prime in a UFD

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have a few doubts regarding the following proof.

> Any irreducible element of a factorial ring $D$ is a prime element of
> $D$.

Proof. Let $p$ be an arbitrary irreducible element of $ D$. Thus $ p$
is a non-unit. If $ ab \in (p)\smallsetminus\{0\}$, then $ ab = cp$
with $ c \in D$. We write $ a,\,b,\,c$ as products of irreducibles:
$$\displaystyle a \;=\; p_1\cdots p_l, \quad b \;=\; q_1\cdots q_m,
 \quad c \;=\; r_1\cdots r_n.$$ Here, one of those first two products may
be empty, i.e., it may be a unit. We have $$\displaystyle p_1\cdots
 p_l\,q_1\cdots q_m \;=\; r_1\cdots r_n\,p\tag{1}$$

Due to the uniqueness of prime factorization, every factor $ r_k$ is
an associate of certain of the $l+m$ irreducibles on the left
hand side of $(1)$. Accordingly, $p$ has to be an associate of one of
the $ p_i$'s or $ q_j$'s. It means that either $ a \in (p)$ or $ b \in
 (p)$. Thus, $ (p)$ is a prime ideal of $ D$, and its generator must be
a prime element.

How can every factor $r_k$ an associate of the irreducibles? Isn't $r_k$ itself irreducible? So it must be equal to one of the irreducible. And why must $p$ be an associate of only one prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say $x$ is an associate of $y$ is to say that $x = yu$ for $u$ some unit. It's not true that $r_k$ must be literally equal to something on the left hand side, e.g. in $\mathbb{Z}$ the equation may read like
$$
(-3)\cdot(-5)\cdot(-7) = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7.
$$
Similarly it's not true that $p$ must be equal to a factor on the left hand side, only that it must be associate. It *is* true, as you say, that $p$ might be associate to more than one of them, e.g. if the equation is
$$
(-3) \cdot (-3) = 3 \cdot 3.
$$
But that's ok, maybe $a \in (p)$ and $b \in (p)$ or maybe two irreducible factors of $a$ are in $(p)$.

Comment: okay! yes! I see! Got it!